# SQL/BigQuery - how to optimize query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find an efficient way of finding out what sessions have three or more records that have the same timestamp

[image]

```
WITH session_base as (
SELECT
   distinct(sessionID),
   TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ContentAccess.timestamp, SECOND) as ets,
   COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM ContentAccess
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING event_count >= 3
)

SELECT distinct(sessionid) from session_base
```

This query takes a very long time to resolve (if ever)., Is there a better way of structuring this query?

Comment: you don't need `distinct` in your CTE because that will be handled with the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select distinct sessionid
from ContentAccess
group by sessionid, timestamp_trunc(timestamp, second)
having count(1) >= 3
```

Comment: @user2868835 - have you tried?